# Chapter heading vertical shift on page with multiple minipages

Tags: chapters, minipage

Im trying to create a document with only minipages to not break the content over different pages. But when the minipages reach the 2nd page of a chapter, the chapter heading layout is shifted vertically and the content of the 1st page is somehow distributed over the entire page instead of top aligned.

I've found that introducing a `\vfill` after the 1st minipage solves the header layout but the other minipages are then placed on the bottom while I want the spacing to be at the bottom.

Any suggestions?

Example:

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}

\chapter{Correct layout}
\begin{minipage}{\textwidth}
\lipsum[1]
\end{minipage}

\chapter{Shifted layout}
\begin{minipage}{\textwidth}
\lipsum[2]
\end{minipage}

\begin{minipage}{\textwidth}
\lipsum[2]
\end{minipage}

\begin{minipage}{\textwidth}
\lipsum[1-2]
\end{minipage}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Maybe `\raggedbottom` can help you. Though I'm not sure if using `minipage`s is the best idea here. Maybe a different solution would fit you better.

Comment: Thanks, that worked perfectly for me. Didn't know that command yet. Currently the minipage with some tweaking works out fine for me. Do you have other suggestions then?

Answer (score 1):

As suggested by moewe
`\raggedbottom` does what I want

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\raggedbottom

\begin{document}

\chapter{Correct layout}
\begin{minipage}{\textwidth}
\lipsum[1]
\end{minipage}

\chapter{No more shift}
\begin{minipage}{\textwidth}
\lipsum[2]
\end{minipage}

\begin{minipage}{\textwidth}
\lipsum[2]
\end{minipage}

\begin{minipage}{\textwidth}
\lipsum[1-2]
\end{minipage}

\end{document}
```